# Pythons requests session to open browser using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im looking to use `requests.session` and `beautifulsoup`. If a specific status of 503 is identified I want to then open that session in a web browser. The problem is I have no idea how to move a python requests session into a browser using selenium. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Requests sessions have [CookieJar](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.cookiejar.html) objects that you can use to import into Selenium.

For example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
s = requests.Session()
s.get('http://example.com')

for cookie in s.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie({
        'name': cookie.name, 
        'value': cookie.value,
        'path': '/',
        'domain': cookie.domain,
    })
```

`driver` should now have all of the cookies (and therefore sessions) that Requests has.